# Does redhat system admin and engineering certificate (RHCSA) and (RHCE) work for all Unix-like operating systems?

Tags: linux, debian, redhat, unix, sysadmin

Does redhat system admin and engineering certificate (RHCSA) and (RHCE) work for all Unix-like operating systems? or
Can a Redhat Engineer or System admin work for a debian based companies or systems?

Answer (score 1):

No, UNIX descended operating systems (AIX, BSD, HP-UX, Solaris) are not Linux. And Red Hat Linux is different from Debian is different from other non-derivative Linux distros. All being inspired by UNIX they will be similar, but the [implementation details are different](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html).

Exams and other formal education are not required to be successful. You may find them useful, depending on your learning style and the expectations of your organization.

Comment: If I study redhat  and get (RHCSA) certifcate, can I be a Debian system administrator too? Because there is only a little difference between Debian and Redhat Linux.